# How to write a file with fs.writeFileSync in a list

Tags: node.js

Im trying to make my first "AI"
that store the words that i use with a "chat bot" everytime that i open
like
if i use "hello" and later i use "Heya" the chatbot will write these words on a json file
And use these words randomly to greet me when i open the program

(At this moment i just trying to write the words on a list, the bot greeting me with these words i already don't created)

heres the code that i tryied:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Hello! ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`The ${answer} word has stored :)`);
  
  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/startkeywords.json', JSON.stringify(answer, null, 4));
  console.log('created at' + __dirname);

  rl.close();
});
```

but, when i execute the program and say something,its writes,but its not on a list
that just writes, so i'm trying to write the file on a list like this:

[list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npSc7.png)

help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store your "keywords" as a **valid** json file, you might need to read file, add data and write again:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const startKeywordsFile = 'startkeywords.json'

// create an empty json if not exists
if (!fs.existsSync(startKeywordsFile)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(startKeywordsFile, '[]')
}
let words = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(startKeywordsFile, 'utf8'))

function addWord(newWord) {
    if (words.includes(newWord)) {
        // already exists
        return
    }
    words.push(newWord)
    fs.writeFileSync(startKeywordsFile, JSON.stringify(words, null, 4))
}

addWord('hi')
addWord('hello')
```

`startkeywords.json`:

```
[
    "hi",
    "hello"
]
```

Keep in mind it might have performance issue with a large list. If you want to save your keywords as plain text (one word a line, not valid json), you can use [`fs.appendFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options) to append your file without having to rewrite the entire file everytime.

Comment: You can replace `]` with `, "${word}" ]` so you don't rewrite 99% of the file, but you'll need to set the location you want to write, see `start` option: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options This way you don't have to read the file in memory, you don't have to parse it, just replace the last bracket with the new word and close the array again. Note that this trick works if the array contains at least 1 element. You probably need to check that the file is at least 4 characters long(2 for `[]`, 2 for `""` in case of empty word)